# "Wav header corrupt" error when trying to play sound more than once

Tags: vb.net

When i try to play a wav file more than once, it throws the error "The wav header is corrupt". The sound plays normally the first time but afterwards it throws the error. The file is in my resources file.

This is the code for playing the sound

```
 If enemy1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(sten.Bounds) Then
            If enemy1alive = 1 Then
                My.Computer.Audio.Play(deathSound, AudioPlayMode.Background)
            End If
            enemy1alive = 0
            enemy1.Location = enemy1spawn
            enemy1.Enabled = False
            enemy1.Visible = False
            score = score + 1
            kills = kills + 1
            kastad = 0
            sten.Location = weaponPosition
            sten.Left = chunkymonkey.Left
            runTimer1.Stop()
            stentimer1.Stop()
```

The wav file is stored in the deathSound variable

Comment: What type is that `deathSound` variable? If it's some type of `Stream` then you may need to reset the pointer, so set `Position` to `0` or call `Seek` to the beginning.

Comment: For future reference, you ALWAYS need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem, so we shouldn't have needed to ask what type that variable is.

Comment: If it's a `String` then it's actually the file path, not the file, that is stored in it, which is something different again. In that case, I'm not sure why that error would occur. You're not trying to play it again while it's still playing, are you? Not sure what would happen in that case.

Comment: Your *deathSound* variable is of type UnmanagedMemoryStream (probably Stream in your code), it is one-time-use.  After it is consumed by the Play() method its Position is at the end of memory block.  It bombs because Play() can not see a valid .wav header in the stream data.  As written, you have to obtain a fresh stream by using My.Resources again.  Google "vb.net play multiple sounds" to find more efficient approaches.

Comment: @HansPassant, the documentation for `UnmanagedMemoryStream` indicates that `CanSeek` is `True` unless the stream is closed. Are you sure you can't just seek back to the start of the same stream? I've never actually tried so don't know.

Comment: You'd have to know when Play() completes, that is not easy. Nor practical in a game.